# django-positions - multi-table model inheritance using parent_link

Tags: python, django

Using https://github.com/jpwatts/django-positions,

I have a few models that inherit from a parent one, for example:

```
class ContentItem(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['position']

    content_group = models.ForeignKey(ContentGroup)
    position      = PositionField(collection='content_group', parent_link='contentitem_ptr')

class Text(ContentItem):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=500, unique=False, null=True, blank=True)
```

I understand I need to [use the parent_link argument](https://github.com/jpwatts/django-positions/blob/master/positions/examples/school/models.py) ([here's the documentation](https://github.com/jpwatts/django-positions)). But I get this error when I use it:

```
websites.Text: (models.E015) 'ordering' refers to the non-existent field 'position'.
```

When using the `parent_link` argument it's as if the `position` field has been deleted out of the model completely. I've tried various field names such as `contentitem_ptr_id` (the actual name of the linking field), but no luck. Anything identifiable I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score -1):

`class Meta:` should come after your field definitions.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't seem to make any difference where the `class Meta:` comes in the model